# Running the same glm model with caret provides different accuracy and errors

Tags: r, r-caret, glm

As stated in the title, running the same glm model with `caret` returns different accuracies and errors (no error OR `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred` OR `1: In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  : prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading`). If I set the seed and always run it with the seed and then the model, predictably I always get the same accuracy and error (or no error) message.

When running the same model with the `glm()` function, coefficients are always the same (as with `caret`), but I never ever get any of the errors in this case. Should I just interpret this as being an issue with resample or may the errors provided by the glm of the `caret` package have any important meaning, if they depend on seed?

I've searched for this and though I assume it has something to do with resampling, I am not quite able to understand how it works and would like assistance in understanding this. Also, I'm trying to use the `caret` package for all the modelling, so I would also like some help trying to understand if I should instead start my process by always running `glm()` instead of through the `caret` package, as this will always provide me the same error message straight away no matter the seed.

Data is from a client, so I'd prefer not to share it. The formula I'm using is (example) simply `train(Y ~ X + Z + A, data = df, method = "glm")` for the `caret` version and `glm(Y ~ X + Z + A, data = df, family = binomial())` in the `glm()` function.

Comment: What is your `trControl` setting? It is possible that the `caret` package uses cross-validation to assess the accuracy, so you got different results. Please share a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: As I've said, data is proprietary so I'd prefer not to share. I was trying to subset a part of it, replicating the issue to no avail though in the meantime I added `trControl=trainControl(method="none")` and it worked perfectly, just as with the `glm()` function. Thanks for the help. If you'd like to comment so I could appoint this thread as resolved, we'd both benefit.

Comment: No reproducible data means what I can do is limited. So good luck.

Comment: It helped incredibly. It is now fixed. thanks